# Java 1.7.0_u25 Applet Debugging with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, applet

I'm trying to debug an applet for 2 days now and I've gone over every solution posted on this site, but i can't find my mistake.

At my Java Runtime Environment Settings i set up all my JREs with the parameters:

```
-Djava.compiler=NONE -Xnoagent -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

When I run the Applet in any browser, and confirm the new security dialog from Java, the Applet starts - all fine.
However, when I run my Debugger in Eclipse with the settings:

- Connection Type: Standard (Socket Attach)
- Host: localhost
- Port: 8000

I get this error:

> 'Launching Applet' has encountered a problem. Failed to connect to remote VM.

In the Details Pane:

> Failed to connect to remote VM Network is unreachable: connect

The output of an Ping to localhost is:

```
ping localhost

Pinging myhostename.mydomain [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
```

What is my awfully ridiculous mistake?

Comment: I have the same problem since java 1.7u21, the last version working is java 1.7u17. I have no solution to your problem however except installing old JVM :). If anyone now how to fix it in newer version please react !

Comment: The old JVM is no option for me, because i need to fix a bug witch only appears on u21 Applets..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sun already fixed that, and the fix will be included in Java 1.7.0 update 40 (released in late August)

Here is the bug-report:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8016154

There is a early access for update 40:
http://jdk7.java.net/download.html

I have not yet tried this but maybe it helps someone out there.

EDIT: Update 40 is now released, I tried it again but it still won't work...
I will continue trying, maybe i did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that 1.7 will not support Applet Debugging... the resolution of the bug is added in 1.8

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8016005

Good thing I found your question/answer, otherwise I might've banged my head the whole day trying to figure out the problem.