# Find Element in Applet

Tags: javascript, applet, firebug

I am attempting to call an element in a third-party website to refresh the webpage, but the "Refresh" button seems to be contained in a separate applet.  I have been researching various methods of accomplishing this (and I am decently familiar with HTML, CSS, Javascript etc.), however I have been unsuccessful in identifying the element in the webpage, and subsequently how to actually call the button.

Here is an image of the "Refresh" button - when I hover the mouse, there is no indication of a link or function to call, and when I use the browser inspector it seems that I can only investigate the border of the page which has the actual HTML:

[image: Genie Screen Capture]

I have tried to use the Firebug plugin for Firefox to view all the script for the page, but it only seems to show me the 'body' or in this case the frame of the website (not the applet itself).  Is there any easier way to find the element, or a program that I can use to simulate the clicking of this "Refresh" button?

Comment: Please clarify what the "applet" contains. If it's a Java applet, there's probably nothing you can do. If it's just an iframe holding an external page, then it depends on which server that page is on.

Comment: I believe it is an iframe, but there is a number of different scripts and I can't seem to locate the refresh element that will call new data from the external page.  When you reference the server that the page is on, how do you recommend identifying that?

Comment: You should be able to use your browser's DOM inspector to identify it and locate the `src` attribute.

Comment: @Blazemonger Thank you for the suggestion!  So if I hover my mouse on the Refresh button, a label appears with "Refresh Data" - if I am searching for the src that references an external JavaScript file, wouldn't that be located somewhere in the HTML?

Comment: Right-click on the applet. If an option called something like "inspect element" appears, select it. The DOM inspector should open and you can browse up the DOM tree through all the parent elements.

Comment: @Blazemonger The developers seem to have disabled the right-click with a var `RIGHT_CLICK_ENABLED = false`... This is where my expertise with HTML and JavaScript is limited.  Can I send a function to my local instance of this applet with the `RIGHT_CLICK_ENABLED = true`?

Comment: Yes, you can. Or just run it in the inspector. Check your browser's documentation for how to use the inspector properly.

Comment: @Blazemonger See this is where I am having trouble - even in Firebug or the Inspector, I cannot seem to locate the Refresh element on that page.  It's as if the button is contained elsewhere not on the local page.

Comment: Without any code or screenshot it is very hard to help. Would it be possible that you edit your question and add more info about the page?

Comment: @SebastianZartner Unfortunately I cannot provide a link or something more detailed, as the page requires a logon to access.  The `Refresh` button reloads the applet, but it seems that none of the variables or functions which are activated in the applet can be viewed through the inspection tool for that webpage.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a link. Some screenshot(s) or code would already help a lot to reproduce the issue. Also, be careful about the terminology. As Blazemonger mentioned, the word 'applet' is associated with Java, i.e. something that is [embedded into your HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26174291/432681) via [`<object>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object). If that's the case, you can't inspect it with Firebug or access it from JavaScript, because it's a self-contained object. So, do you really mean 'Java applet' or do you actually mean JavaScript widget?

Comment: @Sebastian Thank you for the information! I am figuring out that it may be a Java applet instead of an iframe, which I originally thought it was.  The webpage does require Java to run, which coincides with why I can't see functions inside that window.  If it is a Java applet, would there be any way to investigate it?

Comment: Not from within the browser, as far as I know. You'd need to [debug the Java source code of the applet remotely via an IDE like Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6049278/432681) to investigate what it does.

Comment: @SebastianZartner I appreciate the help.  I am currently trying to access the `.class` file, but I am having trouble locating it.  It might be restricted, which might prevent me from being able to debug the source code.  I will try the remote debugging that is suggested in the link!